# Get the name of the openid provider

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, openid, logout

Using OpenID for authentication. How do I get the name of the openid provider once the user is logged in?
The aim would be to pop up a relevant message with the name of the openid provider when the user clicks logout. 
e.g, "Please logout of your google account" if the user is logged in using google as the openid provider.

I was planning to use request.getHeader("Referer");every time a page is loaded and if it contains claimid = google.com then I would set a cookie with the value googleauth. Is that the right way to go. **Any other way I could get the auth provider from userservice**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`google.appengine.api.users.User` object has `federated_provider` method that returns the URL of OpenID provider which was used to authenticate the user. You could use a mapping of this URLs (e.g. using [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openid#OpenID_Providers)) to user-friendly names such as "Google Accounts".